# How to connect my device to Moor Inspector

Tags: flutter, flutter-moor, database-inspector

I was able to download the [Moor inspector plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/15364-database-inspector), but have no idea how to connect the plugin to my device, which requires `Device IP` and `Port` number.

[image]

Comment: It is kinda straightforward what it asks you.

Comment: Yes I know, but how I know the device ip and port number